# Error - 403 Forbidden - Microsoft-Azure-Application-Gateway/v2

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

When I try to send the below request to .net core web api, I am getting the error as "403 Forbidden - Microsoft-Azure-Application-Gateway/v2". I have used the HTML encoding for **encodeEmailBody** property.

**Web Api Code:-**

```
[HttpPut("UpdateEmail")]
[Produces("application/json")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateEmailAsync([FromBody] EmailRequest emailRequest)
{
    var result = await _businessService.UpdateEmailAsync(emailRequest);
    return Ok(result);
}
```

**Request Class**

```
public class EmailRequest
{
    public Guid EmailTemplateTypeId { get; set; }
    public string EncodeEmailSubject { get; set; }
    public string EncodeEmailBody { get; set; }
    public Guid CountryId { get; set; }
}
```

**Request**

```
{
  "emailTemplateTypeId": "4C4B989B-769B-4999-8109-5A51199C09A8",
  "encodeEmailSubject": "test",
  "encodeEmailBody": "&lt;p&gt;The retention file MXMT generation for the &quot;&lt;&lt;EngagementName&gt;&gt;&quot; did not complete successfully.&lt;p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Please contact your local country helpdesk  support function.&lt;p&gt;&lt;hr&gt;&lt;i&gt;This is an automatically generated email. Please do not respond to this email. The mailbox is not b",
  "countryId": "47E37625-ECC5-4F68-ACA6-61432787390D"
}
```

**Error:-**

```
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>Microsoft-Azure-Application-Gateway/v2</center>
</body>
</html>
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
```

**NOTE:** When I call this API locally, it is working fine but not working on **service fabric node**.

Any help will be apricated.

Answer (score 1):

The request is being stopped by the Azure Application Gateway that is in front of your service.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/overview

Azure Application Gateway includes a Firewall (WAF)

The problem is probably that the WAF is flagging your request as malicious. You need to first check the logs on the firewall to see why it is being blocked, then either disable the rule that is blocking the request, or create an exception rule to allow that specific url through.