# Getting 403 Forbidden - Microsoft-Azure-Application-Gateway/v2 when trying to upload particular image to the Azure storage account

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-blob-storage, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-storage-account

I am new to Azure.

when I am trying to upload the particular image through my application to the Azure storage account. I am getting the below error.

`403 Forbidden - Microsoft-Azure-Application-Gateway/v2`

but when I am using another image it is uploading. and my API is returning success code(200).

what can be the root cause for this? why this particular image is not uploading to the blob storage container?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the Web Application Firewall. Could be that you're hitting the upload size limit setup on it or one of the WAF rules is triggered on the request.

Comment: @404 another file with the same size or greater than that is uploading. but don't know what is the issue with that particular image. this image is png image and size is 5 mb

Comment: Check logs on the firewall to see whats going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error usually occurs when the **Azure Application Gateway** stops your request to upload that image.

**Azure Application Gateway** includes a firewall called [Azure Web Application Firewall (WAF)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/web-application-firewall/ag/ag-overview) that provides centralized protection of your web applications from common exploits and vulnerabilities.

While uploading that image to blob storage container, may be the **Azure Web Application Firewall(WAF)** is flagging that request as malicious. The image can also be [malicious](https://gatefy.com/blog/can-images-contain-malicious-code-malware/).

To confirm that, set the **Web Application Firewall (WAF)** in Application Gateway to `Detection` mode and turn on the `Diagnostic logs`. Go through those logs to identify the rule that is blocking the request.

You can avoid that error in 2 ways:

- Go to Web Application Firewall (WAF) rules and **disable** the rule that
  is blocking the request.
- Create a **custom exception rule** to allow that specific image.

Please check below references if they are helpful.

**References:**

[Azure Application Gateway WAF tuning – Kloud Blog](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2018/09/05/azure-application-gateway-waf-tuning/)

[How to Configure Application Gateway in Front of Azure Blob Storage - CHARBEL NEMNOM - MVP | MCT | CCSP - Cloud & CyberSecurity](https://charbelnemnom.com/how-to-configure-application-gateway-in-front-of-azure-blob-storage/)

[c# - Error - 403 Forbidden - Microsoft-Azure-Application-Gateway/v2 - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66821199/error-403-forbidden-microsoft-azure-application-gateway-v2)

Answer (score -2):

One simpler troubleshooting method is to attempt accessing the website that you're experiencing issues with using **Chrome's [Incognito mode](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop)**.

If you can successfully access the website in Incognito mode, it indicates that the problem might be related to your browsing data. In that case, you can resolve the access issue on the normal Chrome browser by **clearing your browsing data**.

To clear your browsing data, follow the steps outlined in the link provided below:

[Link to instructions on clearing browsing data in Chrome](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop)

By following these steps, you should be able to resolve the access issue and use the website normally (not needing Incognito).

Comment: If this answer is entirely by your own hand crafted, then well and good and I withdraw my objection. It comes across using a dry voice often found in AI generated output.